# how to solve an exponential with e base function in python?

Tags: python, sympy, exp

I have this equation that I want to solve in python but I'm not sure if I'm following the right procedure, the equation is ((e^x)* a + b=0) where a and b are constants this my code the output is [-0.916290731874155 + 3.14159265358979*I] which I'm not sure what it means

```
import sympy as sp
​
T_final= 70.0
T_intial= 75.0
T_diff= T_final - T_intial

T_now= 72.0
T_d= T_final - T_now
x = Symbol('x')
​
z= (sp.exp(x)* T_diff)+ T_d
sp.solve(z, x)
```

Comment: The `i * pi` term appears because [`exp(i * pi) == -1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), so if you were expecting there to be a solution in the [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) then you probably got a minus sign the wrong way round.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited a few things and now the answer is [-0.916290731874155 + 3.14159265358979*I] what is I ?

Comment: That is the same thing, just in decimal format.

Comment: yes but what does I stands for?

Comment: See the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

`I` stands for `sqrt(-1)`, e.g. `solve(x**2+1) -> [-I, I]`. When solving the equation `f(x) = a` you have to pass this to `solve` as `solve(f(x) - a, x)` (note the minus on `a`) or as `solve(Eq(f(x), a), x)`.

In your case do you mean

```
>>> solve((sp.exp(x)* T_diff) - T_d, x)  # i.e. Tdiff*e^x = Td
[-0.916290731874155]
```